# Unable to use Mongo Scala driver with case classes

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'm trying to use the Scala mongo driver with case classes, as described at: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/getting-started/quick-tour-case-classes/

However I'm getting the exception:

`Can't find a codec for class com.foo.model.User$.
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.foo.model.User$.`

when I try to insert an item.

The case class:

```
case class User(
               _id: ObjectId,
                foo: String = "",
                foo2: String = "", 
                foo3: String = "",
                first: String,
                last: String,
                username: String,
                pwHash: String = ""
                gender: String,
                isFoo: Boolean = false)
extends FooTrait
```

The code:

```
val providers = fromProviders( classOf[User])

val registry = fromRegistries(providers, DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

val connStr = "mongodb://...."

val clusterSettings = ClusterSettings.builder().applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connStr)).build()
        val clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().codecRegistry(getCodecRegistry).clusterSettings(clusterSettings).build()

val client = MongoClient( clientSettings )
val database: MongoDatabase = client.getDatabase(dbName).withCodecRegistry(registry)

val modelCollection: MongoCollection[User] = db.getCollection("user")

val item = User(.....) //snipped
modelCollection.insertOne(item).toFuture()
```

Full stack trace:

```
Can't find a codec for class com.foo.model.User$.
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class com.foo.model.User$.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.getCodec(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1170)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.getCodec(MongoCollectionImpl.java:1166)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.executeInsertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:519)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:501)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:496)
    at org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection.$anonfun$insertOne$1(MongoCollection.scala:410)
    at org.mongodb.scala.MongoCollection.$anonfun$insertOne$1$adapted(MongoCollection.scala:410)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.ObservableHelper$$anon$2.apply(ObservableHelper.scala:42)
    at org.mongodb.scala.internal.ObservableHelper$$anon$2.apply(ObservableHelper.scala:40)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.requestInitialData(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:38)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.tryRequestInitialData(AbstractSubscription.java:151)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.AbstractSubscription.request(AbstractSubscription.java:82)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedSubscription.request(ObservableImplicits.scala:474)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable$$anon$2.onSubscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:373)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ToSingleObservable$$anon$3.onSubscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:440)
    at org.mongodb.scala.Observer.onSubscribe(Observer.scala:85)
    at org.mongodb.scala.Observer.onSubscribe$(Observer.scala:85)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ToSingleObservable$$anon$3.onSubscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:432)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.SingleResultCallbackSubscription.<init>(SingleResultCallbackSubscription.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.async.client.Observables$2.subscribe(Observables.java:76)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$BoxedObservable.subscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:458)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ToSingleObservable.subscribe(ObservableImplicits.scala:432)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable.headOption(ObservableImplicits.scala:365)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaObservable.head(ObservableImplicits.scala:351)
    at org.mongodb.scala.ObservableImplicits$ScalaSingleObservable.toFuture(ObservableImplicits.scala:410)
```

I think I'm doing everything right - and unless this is a bug, the code should work. My `mongo-scala-driver` version is `2.2.0`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample that is working on my local box with Mongo 3.6.1.

```
// ammonite script mongo.sc
import $ivy.`org.mongodb.scala::mongo-scala-driver:2.2.0`

import org.mongodb.scala._
import org.mongodb.scala.connection._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros._
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromRegistries, fromProviders}

trait FooTrait

case class User(_id: ObjectId,
                foo: String = "",
                foo2: String = "",
                foo3: String = "",
                first: String,
                last: String,
                username: String,
                pwHash: String = "",
                gender: String,
                isFoo: Boolean = false) extends FooTrait

val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[User]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val clusterSettings: ClusterSettings = ClusterSettings.builder().hosts(List(new ServerAddress("localhost")).asJava).build()
val settings: MongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder().clusterSettings(clusterSettings).build()
val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(settings)

val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb").withCodecRegistry(codecRegistry)
val userCollection: MongoCollection[User] = database.getCollection("user")

val user:User = User(new ObjectId(), "foo", "foo2", "foo3", "first", "last", "username", "pwHash", "gender", true)

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
// wait for Mongo to complete insert operation
Await.result(userCollection.insertOne(user).toFuture(),3.seconds)
```

When you save this snippet into a file `mongo.sc`, then you can run it with [Ammonite](http://ammonite.io/) using

```
amm mongo.sc
```

In case mongo is running on the default port, the `mydb` database should get created automatically including the new `user` collection.

Comment: Hmm. I guess the only thing different on my end, is that I'm extending from a trait `DbService[T]` which defines the abstract methods: `def collection =
 Collection[T]` and `def insert(item: T) = collection.insertOne(item)`, this is then extended by `UserService extends DbService[User]` which implements `Collection[User]`. However that doesn't work unless I also have `implicit def ct: ClassTag[T]` in DbService, which is impl'd as : `ClassTag(classOf[User])` in UserService. Could that be why it doesn't work for me, may be its using the class tag rather than the case class to gen. the codec?

Comment: The rest of my code is the same, just the insertion and collection are obtained via DbService and UserService

Comment: It looks like the exception is triggered due to an incomplete codec registry. You should see the same exception you mention in your question, when replacing  the line
`val codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(classOf[User]), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )`
with
`val codecRegistry = fromRegistries( DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY )`
in the script above.